# HTML/CSS - Increased Font-Size Shifts Everything on Page to Left

Tags: html, css

I'm building a site as a learning exercise. It's aim is to showcase some stories, so the readability of the text is quite important.

For the Home, About and similar pages, the layout I have is fine. However, on the pages with a story on, after I increase the font-size to 1.2rem or above, the paragraphs seem to move everything on the page to the left relative to the position of everything on the other pages.

I've set the widths for all of the containers but it doesn't seem to be making a difference.

I've tried isolating the problem and only the font size makes any difference. If I set it lower than 1.2rem it shifts back to its correct position.

The HTML for one of the story pages and the story pages CSS file are below. Any bootstrap terms are just terms I've adopted, they're not using any Bootstrap styling. Trying to build this from the ground up.

Apologies if this is obvious or any of the below is badly formatted / badly written.

Appreciate any help.

Thank you!

```css
        /* Fonts */
    
    /* Montserrat and Raleway */
    
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Raleway');
    
    /* Reset */
    
    * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    html {
     font-size: 16px;
     font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    }
    
    /* Components */
    
    .container {
     width: 66%;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .jumbotron {
     background-color: #ededed;
     padding: 6% 10%;
     margin: 20px;
    }
    
    .jumbotron-header {
     font-size: 2rem;
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    }
    
    /*block size and height, margins left and right slightly*/
    
    .story-text {
     font-size: 1.5rem;
     line-height: 1.5;
     margin: 20px;
     width: 100%;
    }
    
    .story-text > p {
     width: 100%;
    }
    
    .story-subtitle {
     font-size: 2rem;
     font-weight: 600;
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .quote-block {
     margin: 50px 300px;
    }
    
    .quote {
     font-style: italic;
    }
    
    .quote-attribution {
     font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    /* General Styling */
    
    a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: black;
    }
    
    /* Navigation */
    
    /* Layout */
    
    .nav-area {
     display:flex;
     height: 40px;
     background-color: #ededed;
     align-items: center;
    }
    
    .nav-links {
     display: flex;
     flex-grow: 10;
     align-items: center;
    }
    
    .logo-area {
     display: flex;
     flex-grow: 1;
     justify-content: space-around;
     align-items: center;
     background-color: #bcbcbc;
     height: inherit;
    }
    
    
    /* Styling */
    
    #logo {
     font-size: 20px;
     font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .nav-links > div {
     height: 40px;
     line-height: 40px;
    }
    
    .nav-links span {
     font-size: 20px;
     margin: 20px;
     line-height: normal;
     vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .nav-links > div:hover {
     background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    
    
    
    /* Mobile */
    
    /* Burger Menu */
    
    .mobile-nav {
     display: none;
    }
    
    .mobile-menu {
     display: none;
    }
    
    .mobile-menu > div {
     background-color: #ededed;
     border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
     padding: 5%;
    }
    
    .mobile-menu > div:hover {
     background-color: #cecece;
    }
    
    /* Navigation */
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 826px) {
     .nav-area {
      height: auto;
     }
    
     .logo-area {
      padding: 5%;
     }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
     .nav-links {
      display: none;
     }
    
     .mobile-nav {
      display: block;
      margin: 20px;
     }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 740px) {
     .jumbotron-header {
      font-size: 1rem;
     }
    
     .story-text {
      font-size: 1rem;
     }
    
     .story-subtitle {
      font-size: 1.2rem;
     }
    }
```

```html
    <body>
  <!-- Navbar -->

  <header>
   <div class="nav-area container">
    <div class="logo-area">
     <span id="logo"><a href="../index.html">The Lovecraft Project</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-links">
     <div><span><a href="../index.html">Home</a></span></div>
     <div><span><a href="../About-Us/index.html">About</a></span></div>
     <div><span><a href="../Stories/index.html">Stories</a></span></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Burger Menu -->

    <i class="mobile-nav fas fa-bars"></i>

   </div>
  </header>

  <div class="container">

  <!-- Mobile Menu -->

   <div class="mobile-menu">
       <div><a href="../index.html">Home</a></div>
    <div><a href="../About-Us/index.html">About</a></div>
    <div><a href="../Stories/index.html">Stories</a></div>
   </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Content -->

  <div class="container">

   <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="jumbotron-header">
     <h1>The Shadow Over Innsmouth</h1>
     <hr>
     <p>H.P. Lovecraft</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="story-text">
    <p class="story-subtitle">I.</p>
    <p>During the winter of 1927–28 officials of the Federal government made a strange and secret investigation of certain conditions in the ancient Massachusetts seaport of Innsmouth. The public first learned of it in February, when a vast series of raids and arrests occurred, followed by the deliberate burning and dynamiting—under suitable precautions—of an enormous number of crumbling, worm-eaten, and supposedly empty houses along the abandoned waterfront. Uninquiring souls let this occurrence pass as one of the major clashes in a spasmodic war on liquor.</p>

    <p>Keener news-followers, however, wondered at the prodigious number of arrests, the abnormally large force of men used in making them, and the secrecy surrounding the disposal of the prisoners. No trials, or even definite charges, were reported; nor were any of the captives seen thereafter in the regular gaols of the nation. There were vague statements about disease and concentration camps, and later about dispersal in various naval and military prisons, but nothing positive ever developed. Innsmouth itself was left almost depopulated, and is even now only beginning to shew signs of a sluggishly revived existence.</p>

    <p>Complaints from many liberal organisations were met with long confidential discussions, and representatives were taken on trips to certain camps and prisons. As a result, these societies became surprisingly passive and reticent. Newspaper men were harder to manage, but seemed largely to coöperate with the government in the end. Only one paper—a tabloid always discounted because of its wild policy—mentioned the deep-diving submarine that discharged torpedoes downward in the marine abyss just beyond Devil Reef. That item, gathered by chance in a haunt of sailors, seemed indeed rather far-fetched; since the low, black reef lies a full mile and a half out from Innsmouth Harbour.</p>

    <p>People around the country and in the nearby towns muttered a great deal among themselves, but said very little to the outer world. They had talked about dying and half-deserted Innsmouth for nearly a century, and nothing new could be wilder or more hideous than what they had whispered and hinted years before. Many things had taught them secretiveness, and there was now no need to exert pressure on them. Besides, they really knew very little; for wide salt marshes, desolate and unpeopled, keep neighbours off from Innsmouth on the landward side.</p>

    <p>But at last I am going to defy the ban on speech about this thing. Results, I am certain, are so thorough that no public harm save a shock of repulsion could ever accrue from a hinting of what was found by those horrified raiders at Innsmouth. Besides, what was found might possibly have more than one explanation. I do not know just how much of the whole tale has been told even to me, and I have many reasons for not wishing to probe deeper. For my contact with this affair has been closer than that of any other layman, and I have carried away impressions which are yet to drive me to drastic measures.</p>

   </div>

  </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Resources/Scripts/script.js"></script>

 </body>
```

Comment: Change `rem` to `px`. 1.2rem to 12px

Comment: Is the entire page itself shifting to the left or just the text? Could it be the increased font size is increasing the vertical height of the page and causing the scrollbar to appear?

Comment: @salarimameri doesn't 1.2rem = nearly 20px - rem is set on the base font size - in this case 16px

Comment: @JosephWebber is correct! Can't believe I've spent so long bashing my head against this problem. Thank you for pointing the scrollbar out!

also, Pete, sorry should have been clearer, it was the font size for the paragraphs in the .story-text div

Comment: First also use *{padding:0; margin:0;} to avoid any additional spacing and jumping then use percents instead of pexels. Also kindly give your precious minutes to read https://css-tricks.com/content-jumping-avoid/                                                It will solve your problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is, whenever you are increasing the font-size it is aligning itself accordingly inside the fixed width that you have provided. So, in order to get the desired layout every time use percentages rather than fixed values.